# Use SMS Emulator from Android Test Case

Tags: android, unit-testing, continuous-integration, sms, emulation

I want to automate functional testing of my code which works with SMS. I know, that I can use `send sms` command and sms will be sent to emulator instance.

The question is how can I execute `send sms` command programmatically from my test case, so I can run test without manual intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you managed to resolve this issue, but I did it by using telnet.

I'm using the emulator, and the emulator listens on localhost.

First I used a port forwarder (http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) to forward connections going to my local IP address port 5554 (or whatever port the emulator listens to) to 127.0.0.1:5554.

Having that configured you can send an sms to the emulator by using telnet to your local IP address (eg. sms send 1111 message)

Now, from the unit test I can open a socket connection to my local ip address and issue the sms send command, thus effectively sending an SMS from the emulator to itself in the unit tests.

A bit of a pain but it works.